# Hibernate mapping many-to-many with composite key

Tags: hibernate, mapping, many-to-many, composite-primary-key

I have these tables (with these primary keys):

**Resources**
- idResource (PK)
- idResLanguage (PK)

**Tags**
- idTag (PK)

**Resources_Tags**
- idResource (PK)
- idTag(PK)

Is there any way to map these tables only referencing the field "idResource" in the **Resources_Tags** table?

I'm asking this because if I don't put idResLanguage at the **Resources_Tags** table at the time that I do the Hibernate's reverse engineering on Eclipse it throws this error:

**"MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `idResource` is sufficient to uniquely identify a Resource, then it should be the primary key, and `idResLanguage` should not be part of the primary key.

If it's not sufficient to uniquely identify a Resource, then you need it in the join table, else it would not map one resource with one tag, but many resources with one tag.